# Sprite removal only when 'score' is met - Python

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am relatively new to python and have started making a small space invaders style game, in which you play as an alien invading earth. The last level involves shooting at the earth to win the game. I have set it so the earth has a health of 500 and each time it is hit it decreases by 10. Once the health of the earth reaches 0, I wish to remove the image and play an explosion type sound along with a congratulations message, currently I have this code:

```
earth_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
earthlife = 500

...

class Earth(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Files/Images/Earth.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 400
        self.rect.y = 0
        self.earthlife = 500

...

for i in range(1):
    earth = Earth(BLACK)
    block.rect.x = 400
    block.rect.y = 0
    earth_list.add(earth)
    all_sprites_list.add(earth)

...

for bullet in bullet_list:

    earth_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, earth_list, True)

    for earth in earth_hit_list:
        explosion.play()
        earthlife -= 10

        if earthlife == 0 and health >=25:
            win.play()
            label = font.render("GAME COMPLETE", 1, (0,255,0))
            labelRect = label.get_rect()
            labelRect.center = (400, 250)
            labelC = font.render("PRESS ENTER TO RETURN TO MAIN MENU", 1, GREEN)
            labelCRect = labelC.get_rect()
            labelCRect.center = (250, 300)
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            break

    if earthlife == 0:
        collision.stop()
        laser.stop()
        explosion.stop()
        earth_list.remove(earth)
        all_sprites_list.remove(earth)
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)
```

However it doesnt seem to be functioning properly and the earth image gets removed on the first hit from my ships bullet, regardless of its health level. Here is the rest of my code in case it helps anyone:
http://pastebin.com/p82JGs6q

Any help as to why this might not be working properly would be welcomed. Thank you :)

Comment: Please put the relevant code (and [only the relevant code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) *here*: where is `earthlife` assigned; where is it modified; where is it tested?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks a lot for your reply, I have added the necessary code above, I apologise in advance if there are any mistakes present :)

Answer (score 1):

You never actually remove bullet from bullet_list unless earthlife == 0. Since everything is in a while True: loop, your single bullet keeps hitting earth until it dies.

edit: I noticed that you are removing the bullet if bullet.rect.y < -10. If bullet hits the earth, will it keep going until that if statement is satisfied?